# The points $r =(-4, 3),\ s= (7, 4)$ and $t= (8, -7)$ lie on a circle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Can someone please help me find the centre of the circle?

Okay guys, this is what I've done so far

So you need to find the perpendicular bisector of two chords

So for chord RS
y - (1/11)x = 37/11

And for chord ST
y + (11)x = -41

Solving through simultaneous equations, I got x =-4, and y =3 as the centre

But the answer has to be x = 2, and y = -2

Can someone explain to me where I went wrong? :/

Comment: Whenever you post any question on this site, do include your own work on the problem and the efforts you have made so that we can provide some "specific" help .....

Comment: Please try to make your title more informative....

Comment: I've done that, but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: but you need perpendicular bisector of it

Comment: What is the bisector of $ST$.?

Comment: The bisector of $ST$ is $y=\dfrac{1}{11}x-\dfrac{24}{11}$.

Comment: y - 7/2 = -11 (x-3/2); y = -11x + 20

Comment: ok. and their contact?

Answer (score 1):

$(2,-2)$ of course!

Let $A(-4,3)$, $B(7,4)$ and $C(8,-7)$

Hence, $\measuredangle ABC=90^{\circ}$

Comment: Can you explain this more?

Comment: 2,-2 is just the midpoint of AC, not the centre of the circle

Comment: @Raj2000 Since $\measuredangle ABC=90^{\circ}$, it's the centre of the circle exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Roughly plot those points on paper and notice that the slope of line joining the points $r$ and $s$ is let $m_1$=$\frac{1}{11}$ and that of line joining $s$ and $t$ is let $m_2$=$-11$. This tells us that they are perpendicular lines and meet on the circle at point $s$ at right angle and hence $rt$ is the diametre of circle. So centre of circle is midpoint of $r$ and $t$ =$(2,-2)$.

Comment: Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: Are my simultaneous equations correct?

Comment: I got y +3/2 = 1/11 (x-[15/2])

Comment: This gives y - 1/11x - 15/22 -3/2

Comment: This gives y - 1/11x = -24/11

Comment: @Raj2000 sorry, Your equations should be -11(x-3/2)=y-7/2   and 1/11(x-15/2)=y+3/2

Answer (score 0):

Find the attache solution as an image file. 
Solve those system of equation.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me solve the equations please?

Comment: How do you solve the equations?

Comment: Its $3 \times 3$ equation that you can solve by elimination method.

Answer (score 0):

The bisector of $ST$ is $y=\dfrac{1}{11}x-\dfrac{24}{11}$.

The bisector of $RS$ is $y=-11x+20$.

The contact of $ST$ and $RS$ is $(2,-2)$.

Note that the solution of Michael Rozenberg is genius. Plot points and check that $AC^2=AB^2+BC^2$ so $B=90^\circ$ and $AC$ will be the diameter of the circle, then the center of circle is the midpoint of $AC$.

Comment: I just saw that $\frac{1}{11}\cdot(-11)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You made two separate but related mistakes. The equation that you have for the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{RS}$ is actually the equation of the line that passes through those two points. You second equation is that of a line parallel to $\overline{ST}$, but that passes through $R$. When you computed their intersection, you of course got back the coordinates of the point $R$.

Without seeing the details of your work, it’s hard to say exactly where you went wrong, but at the very least, it looks like you confused the direction vector of a line with its normal (perpendicular) vector. That is, instead of using the slope $m$ for each of the lines, you ended up getting $-1/m$ instead, which is at right angles to the correct slope.